# SQLite ExecuteNonQuery doesn't let me close the connection afterwards

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(...)
string query = "INSERT INTO Account(col1, col2, col3) VALUES(\"test\", \"some\", \"thing\")";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, myConnection);
myConnection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
```

Running the debugger, the code gets to command.ExecuteNonQuery() and then never hits myConnection.Close(). Is there any particular reason for this?

Running the query with the Insert statement never allows me to close the connection, but changing the query to "select * from table" works just fine.

Comment: What do you use in `query` - what statements??

Comment: added an edit for the query statement as well as desired behavior and current behavior.